# rqt_graph not showing all active nodes

Tags: ros, action, ros-kinetic, actionlib-tutorials, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been following through the simple examples for actions and I'm not sure how to change the setting to get rqt_graph to show nodes a level "deeper".

The action is questions is an exact copy of the ones used in: [link](https://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/RunningServerAndClient)

The action node graph they get is: [image: image description]

The graph I get instead is: [image: image description]

and calling `rostopic list -v` returns:

`morten@mortenThinkPad:~$ rostopic list`

`/fibonacci/cancel /fibonacci/feedback /fibonacci/goal /fibonacci/result /fibonacci/status /rosout /rosout_agg`

I'm relatively new to ROS so I'm not quite sure what other information could be relevant. I'm running ubuntu 16.04LTS with ROS kinetic.

edit: adding picture now that I have enough karma

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325235/rqt_graph-not-showing-all-active-nodes/) by [morten_nissov](https://answers.ros.org/users/42355/morten_nissov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-06-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-11**:\

> I would like to upload a picutre but I don't have enough karma.

you do now.

Please attach the image directly to the question.

**Comment by [morten_nissov](https://answers.ros.org/users/42355/morten_nissov/) on 2019-06-11**:
Thanks for the reminder, I've just done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you are seeing is the ROS *nodes*. They are shown in bubbles whereas the ROS *topics* are shown in rectangles. If you want to see both you need to select the drop-down menu from the top-left corner and change it from "Nodes only" to "Nodes/Topics (all)"

---

Originally posted by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) with karma: 2327 on 2019-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [morten_nissov](https://answers.ros.org/users/42355/morten_nissov/) on 2019-06-11**:
After selecting the "nodes/topics (all)" topic the graph doesn't change. Do I need to reload the image.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2019-06-11**:
Possibly yes - click the circular blue arrow in the top-left corner to reload the graph. If that doesn't work, add  a screen shot to your question (as gvdhoorn suggested) and add the output of `rostopic list`.

**Comment by [morten_nissov](https://answers.ros.org/users/42355/morten_nissov/) on 2019-06-11**:
The formatting got a little weird but I've added the output from `rostopic list` as well.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-11**:
@morten_nissov: you have "group namespaces" and "group actions" enabled. That is why your graph looks different from the one shown in the tutorial.

**Comment by [morten_nissov](https://answers.ros.org/users/42355/morten_nissov/) on 2019-06-11**:
Ah okay, I'll try again without then.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-11**:
You'll also want to uncheck all the options in the *Hide* section.